# NLP model - Arabic diacritized_text [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, arabic

i am trying to read  diacritized_text  from pdf file by using this code:

```
import PyPDF2 
import pdfplumber.utils
import pdfminer.pdftypes
import arabic_reshaper
from pdfplumber.pdf import PDF
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
#import pyPdf
import codecs
input_filepath = "D:\Arabic research\input.pdf" file path
output_filepath = "D:\Arabic research\output.txt"#output text file path
output_file = open(r"D:\Arabic research\output.txt", "wb")#open output file
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(codecs.open(r"D:\Arabic research\input.pdf", "rb", encoding='utf-8'))#read PDF
for page in PyPDF2.pages:#loop through pages
    page_text = page.extractText()#get text from page
    page_text = page_text.decode(encoding='utf-8')#decode 
    print(page_text)
    output_file.write(page_text)#write to file
output_file.close()#close
```

but i have the following error:[Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: The error seems related to the file name, not the actual code. Could you please [edit] to show the full traceback?

Comment: I notice that you lack the `r` prefix on the first two file names, so that's probably your bug. If that's not it, please revert and clarify.

Comment: For legibility, probably put spaces on both sides of the `#` comment character.